# How to display all properties of an object on another component after selecting one of its object.property on react?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am creating an app where I have an employee object stored in `localhost://8081/employee` . The object has 5 properties- `empid` (string), `name`, `email`, `mobile` and `age`. My `employee-list` page is currently displaying a list of `empid` and `name` and when a name is clicked, using router it should open `employee-details` component below it which would display all 5 properties of the selected employee at the bottom of the page. The router and the list name and empid list work but the expansion on click is not displaying the right data and I'm wondering how to fix it. When I console.log `this.target.value`, I am always getting `0` though I should be getting the selected employee's data. How can I pass the data to the `employee-details` component and display the whole object in `employee-details` component? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, like a lot, thank you!

employee-list.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './employees-list.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import EmployeeDetails from './employee-details/employee-details';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class EmployeesList extends Component{
    
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            employees : []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getEmps();
    }

    getEmps() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8081/employee')
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({ employees : res.data });
            console.log(res.data); 
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        });
    }

    selectEmp = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.value)
    }

    render() {
        const{ name } = this.state;
        return(
            <Router>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-2">
                        <h6 className="font-weight-bold">Employee ID</h6>
                        {this.state.employees.map(employee => <li>{employee.empid}</li>)}
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-2">
                        <h6 className="font-weight-bold">Name</h6>
                        <Link to="/emplist/empid">{this.state.employees.map(
                            employee => <li value={this.state.employees.empid} onClick={e => this.selectEmp(e, "value")}>{employee.name}</li>)}</Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/emplist/empid">
                            <EmployeeDetails/>
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
        
    }
}
```

employee-details.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import './employees-details.css';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class EmployeeDetails extends Component{
    
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            employee : []
        }
    }

    render() {
        const{ employee } = this.state;
        return(
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-2">
                    <h6 className="font-weight-bold">Employee ID</h6>
                    {this.state.employee.empid}
                </div>
                <div className="col-2">
                    <h6 className="font-weight-bold">Name</h6>
                    {this.state.employee.name}
                </div>
                {/* <div className="col-2">
                    <h6 className="font-weight-bold">Age</h6>
                    {this.state.employee.age}
                </div>
                <div className="col-3">
                    <h6 className="font-weight-bold">Email</h6>
                    {this.state.employee.email}
                </div>
                <div className="col-2">
                    <h6 className="font-weight-bold">Mobile</h6>
                    {this.state.employee.mobile}
                </div> */}
            </div>
        )
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In state add new property:

```
this.state = {
   employees : [],
   selectedEmpl : {}
}
```

Edit `selectEmpl` handler as:

```
selectEmp = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    const empl = this.state.employees.filter((emp)=> emp.empid === e)[0] || {};   
    this.setState({ ...this.state, selectedEmpl : empl });
}
```

Then pass `selectedEmpl` as props:

```
<EmployeeDetails employee={this.state.selectedEmpl}/>
```

Few changes in `EmployeeDetails` component:
You are destructuring `state` to get `employee`, so there's no need to do `this.state` or `this.props` down in the `render()`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import './employees-details.css';
axios from 'axios';

export default class EmployeeDetails extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

render() {
    const { employee } = this.props;
    return(
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-2">
                <h6 className="font-weight-bold">Employee ID</h6>
                {employee.empid}
            </div>
            <div className="col-2">
                <h6 className="font-weight-bold">Name</h6>
                {employee.name}
            </div>
            {/* <div className="col-2">
                <h6 className="font-weight-bold">Age</h6>
                {employee.age}
            </div>
            <div className="col-3">
                <h6 className="font-weight-bold">Email</h6>
                {employee.email}
            </div>
            <div className="col-2">
                <h6 className="font-weight-bold">Mobile</h6>
                {employee.mobile}
            </div> */}
        </div>
    )
    
}
}
```